# How to check whether MFA is enabled for root account in AWS using boto?

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, boto

I am working on trusted advisor and need to check whether MFA is enabled for root level also?
Its in Security section of Trusted advisor Dashboard. 
I am working in Python using Boto.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use the `GetAccountSummary` API call in IAM which is available as the `get_account_summary` method call in `boto.iam.IAMConnection`.

```
import boto.iam
conn = boto.iam.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
summary = conn.get_account_summary()
```

This returns a Python dictionary containing a lot of information about your account.  Specifically, to find out if MFA is enabled;

```
if summary['AccountMFAEnabled']:
    # MFA is enabled
else:
    # MFA is not enabled
```

Comment: But will this check whether the MFA is enabled for ROOT account??

Comment: Yes.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccountSummary.html for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I don't have 15 credits now...thats why not able to accept the answer :( Will do that soon !! :)

Comment: You don't have to have 15 reputation points to accept an answer.  By accepting the answer, the author of the answer is awarded 15 points and you are awarded 2. It never costs you reputation to credit a correct answer. That would be counter-productive for the stack overflow community.

Answer (score 5):

This answer updates to boto3 and assumes that you have only one account configured in your ~/.aws/config or ~/.aws/credentials file:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

if client.get_account_summary()['SummaryMap']['AccountMFAEnabled']:
    root_has_mfa = True
else:
    root_has_mfa = False
```

If you'd prefer to have the dictionary that get_account_summary returns, you can do that too:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

summary = client.get_account_summary()['SummaryMap']

if summary['AccountMFAEnabled']:
    root_has_mfa = True
else:
    root_has_mfa = False
```